# WinRT Acessing GridView in a Listview in a Grid

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a Grid with a GridView and a ListView in it. I would like to change the datatemplate of the GridView while the program is running by using GridView.ItemTemplate, but the problem is I cannot access the name of the GridView. The sample of the code:

```
<Grid>
 ... Some Grid properties, etc
<Text> ...Some Text above to accompany the desciprition of listview
<ListView x:Name = "somethinginthemiddle"
... ListView properties, location in grid, etc.>
...
<Grid>
<GridView x:Name = "IWantToAccessThis"
</GridView>
</ListView>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Edit: Might worth noting that there may be more than one gridview generated. Should I attempt to go through ListView children?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the x:Name property of that GridView? Or is it you cannot access the GridView with its name?

Comment: The gridview has its Name, in this case IWantToAccessThis, however, I cannot access it from the code.

Comment: Like IWantToAccessThis.Name? You can't do that, or at least no easy way. I can explain more if this is your question.

Comment: IWantToAccessThis.ItemTemplate would be my target.

Comment: I'm not sure but your code seems to be a little messy, how can you place a GridView under a Grid? If your code became: <ListView x:Name = "somethinginthemiddle">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name = "IWantToAccessThis">
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
you can definitely access "IWantToAccessThis".

Comment: Sadly you cant access the `gridview` directly using name property as now your `gridview` is an ItemTemplate of your `Listview`. You would need to access the itemtemplate of your listview firt then typecast it as gridview and access that itemtemplate

Comment: How would I go about casting itemtemplate to gridview? It doesn't allow me to do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful.

In the xaml file:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="LightGray" Height="200" Width="200">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="48" Foreground="Green"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="White">
    <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
    <ListView x:Name = "somethinginthemiddle">
        <Grid>
            <GridView x:Name = "IWantToAccessThis">
                <GridView.Items>
                    <x:String>One</x:String>
                    <x:String>Two</x:String>
                </GridView.Items>
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </ListView>            
</Grid>
```

In the xaml.cs file:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        IWantToAccessThis.ItemTemplate = Resources["TestTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
    }
```

Here you can see how to get access to `IWantToAccessThis` and how to set the `ItemTemplate` on this control.